# Execute DDL statements from a query in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to do this in a stored procedure:

1. Query a specific database, dump results in a table
2. The results contain DDL statements such as alter, create, IF exists...
3. Execute the results from step 2 as if executing them in a query window via SSMS

Example of step 2 results are:

1. Alter database.....
2. exec sp_addmember....
3. If not exists....

I'm couldn't find a good way to perform step 3, any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cursor to loop through the table, then use `EXEC sys.sp_executesql` for each row.

The following code relies on a temporary table, named `#t`, which contains various DML statements:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t;
CREATE TABLE #t 
(
    cmdOrder int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , cmd nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #t (cmd)
VALUES (N'SELECT 1')
    , (N'SELECT 2');

DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC
FOR
SELECT t.cmd
FROM #t t
ORDER BY t.cmdOrder;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @cmd;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;
    PRINT N'';
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

The output looks like:

[image]

Compound statements, like `IF EXISTS (...)` must occur in a single statement.  If you need to run all rows as if they were a single statement, simply concatenate the output from each row, then use `sys.sp_executesql` on the result, as in:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t;
CREATE TABLE #t 
(
    cmdOrder int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , cmd nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #t (cmd)
VALUES (N'IF (1=2)')
    , (N'PRINT N''yes''')
    , (N'ELSE')
    , (N'PRINT N''no''');

DECLARE @line nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC
FOR
SELECT t.cmd
FROM #t t
ORDER BY t.cmdOrder;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @line;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = @cmd + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @line;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @line;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;
```

The output from the above code:

```
no
```

If you are allergic to cursors, you could use a set-based approach, such as:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max) = '';
SELECT @cmd = CASE WHEN @cmd = '' THEN '' ELSE @cmd END + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + t.cmd
FROM #t t
ORDER BY t.cmdOrder;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;
```

Understand there is a slight chance that using the set-based approach with string concatenation may cause the commands to be executed in the wrong order, even though there is an `ORDER BY` clause.  The SQL Server query optimizer can do strange things under the hood if it thinks the query will perform faster.